# custom ssl in windows azure

Tags: ssl, azure

I was evaluating appharbor and azure framework or a cloud application. 
I came across an article in this url: http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/06/10/some-notes-on-the-recent-azure-launch , which says

> Azure Web Sites has no way to add your own SSL certificates at all. If your app needs SSL, you’re stuck with running on the Azure subdomain and piggy-backing off their certificate.

I am a little confused here and so the question:

1) Does this mean that I cannot register and use a ssl certificate for my domain (eg: www.mydomain.com) if my application is hosted in azure? 
If that cannot be done- isnt this a fairly basic requirement for a secure web application? why is it not implemented in azure?

2) Azure articles talk of shared ssl certificate. So, if I use a shared certificate, what will the user see in certificate details? will they see something like  myapplication.cloudapp.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true as of today. But please do note that Azure Web Sites is a **preview** feature and things **do change**. Having a custom SSL certificate for an Azure Web Sites is something that the team in Redmond is definitely after (check [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/0218204f-7be3-4586-bfdb-831cde6b7937)). Also, please do note that this limitation is only valid for [Windows Azure Web Sites](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/). Website addresses usually maps to myapp.azurewebsites.net.

This is not the situation with [Windows Azure Cloud Services](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/cloud-services/) (that maps to myapp.cloudapp.net). You check some articles and sample how to configure custom SSL for Azure Cloud services [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl/) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/28/complete-solution-adding-ssl-certificate-with-windows-azure-application.aspx).

Comment: I did not know about the new "azure web sites" - which I understand  is different from the normal web applications hosting in azure.

Answer (score 0):

Azure websites now do support SSL certificates, with the ability to buy an SSL certificate or bring your own.

see this article for the configuration:
https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Also free SNI certificates are available as of now for Basic, Standard and Premium App Services:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/ssl-connection-pricing-changes/